# Userform, how to add date filter range

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I wish to use Userform option for date filters, user will enter "start time" & "end time" and all relevant data will be displayed according to this filter.

I used local Macro that use two different cells for data input but file view is bad and this is the reason I want to use Useform option.

My code:

```
Public Sub MyFilter()
    Dim lngStart As Date, lngEnd As Date
    lngStart = Range("b2").Value 'assume this is the start date
    lngEnd = Range("b3").Value 'assume this is the end date
    Range("q:q").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd


           Range("A1:s3000").Select
    Range("A:A").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Cells.Select
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Rows("1:1").Select
    .Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection
         With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 15773696
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .AutoFilter
           Columns("Q:Q").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]m/d/yy h:mm AM/PM;@"
    End With
    .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Range("A2").Select
End With

End Sub
```

The code also copy the data to a new sheet ( any idea how to copy it to a new file?) and changed some cells format.

Thanks!!

Comment: So your question is "how to copy data from a userform to a worksheet?" or is there something else you're asking? What part of this is your code getting done, which part are you stuck on, and what have you tried?  (See also, "[ask]" as well as "[mcve]".)

Comment: The code I wrote is working on regular Macro.. I want to edit it to Userform option with two different bottoms of "Start time", "End time" and than run it (each button should be able to get date value from the user like "b2" & "b3" cells in my code.

Answer (score 0):

For copying paste buffer to a new file, add a new file (instead of a sheet):

```
Set fNew = = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
 ...
fNew.SaveAs Filename:=<file specification>
```

`Paste:=xlPasteValues` literally copies values without any formatting, comments, borders, etc. For keeping source format, simply use `ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A1")`. If - for any reason - it does not work, you can try this:

```
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

For copying only the filtered rows, use this:

```
Range("A1:S3000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
fNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: thanks but I have no idea how to edit it to userform view.